# fillable insertable Checkbox by hyperref package

Tags: pdftex, forms

I tried to construct a LaTeX file to design a checklist with the options: Yes, No, or N/A.

What I need is a PDF-File with a feature to insert one of these options from the PDF file (Not from .tex file) as shown by the attached image.

[image]

It would be better, if it is possible for example by "No" option, to insert "xmark" and by "N/A" somehow red sign.

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\HyField@FlagsRadioButton}{\HyField@SetFlag{Ff}{Radio}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\def\DefaultOptionsofRadio{print}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        {Choose one of the following !}%
        \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{52},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{Yes=Yes}
        \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{55},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{No=No}
        \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=\ding{117},name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons]{}{Not Available=NA}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/115178)

Comment: I posed this question and after a while I figured it out by myself and I would to share it with others in this forum. Since this forum always helps me alot !

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry!  I thought this was an attempt to add an MWE to the question.  Could you add a few lines to explain how this works to help others finding this in the future?  Code-only answers can be a bit difficult to follow and a little explanation can be useful to work out how to adapt solutions to individual purposes which may all differ a bit, images of the code output can also be helpful to illustrate clearly what the achieved result looks like.

Comment: You might also try \ding{53}, ding{110} and color=red.  You will need to add \usepackage{xcolor} before hyperref.

Comment: I am still new learner by LaTeX and I found this code by one of the pages by this forum and I modified it a little bit. Unfortunately, I do not much time to explain every line, since I have some reports those should be submitted asap. I am sorry for that. Next time, I will explain and comment every code line I post it here !