# whilenum loop to generate \dotfill lines on a twocolumn article

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to create a to-do list that I can print out/use on my computer each day depending upon where I am working from (home or lab). I used the self-answer [by Ali Mansour contained here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354654/273733) to create a `\ChoiceMenu` using `hyperref` (for which I have 0 experience with). So far, the document is going well but I would also like for there to be a **Comments** section in the right column of the `[twocolumn]{article}` filled with `\dotfill`s aligned to each of the entries. My efforts with `\@whilenum` have not worked and whilst I am comfortable with while and for loops in other languages, I have no experience with them in latex. The code I currently have produces this:

[image]

The numbers at the start of the lines were my attempt at debugging as if `\theentryzcount` is removed from the line

> ```
> {\dotfill\newline\addtocounter{entryzCount}{-1}\theentryzCount}
> ```

it only prints the one line:

[image]

My issues are:

1. How can I have dotted lines aligned to the `entryz` within a `while` or `for` loop depending on how many `entryz` there are?
2. When I go to print the document to pdf, the `backgroundcolor` of the `checkbox`es is still grey and not white, I looked at the relevant [`hyperref` manual sections (p. 43)](https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf) but could not see how to force the background of the box to be white? (see next figure)

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=1.61cm,outer=1.61cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,columnsep=12pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354654/273733
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\HyField@FlagsRadioButton}{\HyField@SetFlag{Ff}{Radio}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\def\DefaultOptionsofRadio{print}

\newcounter{entryzCount} \setcounter{entryzCount}{0}
\newcommand\entryz[1]{\addtocounter{entryzCount}{1}\item #1 \dotfill%
    \ChoiceMenu[radio,
                    radiosymbol=\ding{52},
                    name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons,
                    bordercolor=black,
                    backgroundcolor=white]{}{=Yes}%
    }

\begin{document}
\noindent\textbf{Items to be completed}
\begin{Form}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm]
    \entryz{Text to go in the field}
    \entryz{More text to go in the field that is longer}
    \entryz{More text to go in the field}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Form}

\newpage
\hfill\textbf{Comments}
\newline\theentryzCount
\makeatletter
\@whilenum\value{entryzCount}>0\do
{\dotfill\newline\addtocounter{entryzCount}{-1}\theentryzCount}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

I am assuming a table would be better but I am not sure how to merge say `tabularx` and `ChoiceMenu`. I am happy to accept any solution using any method if 1 is answered, 2 is a bonus to reduce potential printing ink usage please. The document will never be longer then 1 page so hopefully that makes it easier.

(PS I could not think of a relevant tag to put on this so I just used `pdftex`, I know that is not an accurate tag but unsure what is? Please feel free to edit to its correct or better tags, I had to put one to submit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using two column format, use boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=1.61cm,outer=1.61cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354654/273733
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\HyField@FlagsRadioButton}{\HyField@SetFlag{Ff}{Radio}}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\DefaultOptionsofRadio}{print}

\newcommand\entryz[1]{%
  \item
    \makebox[0.48\textwidth][s]{%
      #1 \dotfill
      \ChoiceMenu[
        radio,
        radiosymbol=\ding{52},
        name=myGroupOfRadiobuttons,
        bordercolor=black,
        backgroundcolor=white
      ]{}{=Yes}%
    }\hspace{0.04\textwidth}\dotfill\par
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\makebox[0.48\textwidth][l]{\textbf{Items to be completed}}%
\hspace{0.04\textwidth}\textbf{Comments}

\begin{Form}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm]
    \entryz{Text to go in the field}
    \entryz{More text to go in the field that is longer}
    \entryz{More text to go in the field}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]